# How to store a byte into an ISE RAM?

Tags: fpga

I'm new to fpga. I'm designing a simple RISC-V CPU using ISE but I met some problems.

In a 32-bit RISC-V CPU, there are different instructions for storing, which are sw, sh and sb. And during the instruction decoding part, the processor determines whether it wants to store a word, halfword or byte. So it's necessary that we let the processor output a control signal (DMType, namely data memory type) and the data memory should receive it as input.

However, when using ISE RAM, I found that there's no such a interface like DMType to determine the way the processor stores the data. I've no idea what to do. Please give me some advice:)

Comment: Not sure what "ISE RAM" is -- is it a reference to the old Xilinx ISE development environment? In any case, if you want byte addressability in a 32-bit architecture, you're generally going to have to implement your memory as four separate 8-bit wide memories, and decode the specific write enables for each of them from the "DMType" parameter and the low-order address bits.

Comment: Yeah, as Dave says: you will need to write a wrapper for your specific memory that can do that.